# Migrating to Retrospectiva

Tags: ruby, migration, trac, retrospectiva

We're interested in an Agile PM System and have picked out Retrospectiva. We really need to be able to migrate tickets out of our existing system and were interested in taking a look at the migration scripts.

In their wiki they link to two scripts (trac and collaboa) http://retrospectiva.org/wiki/Migration

However taking a look at their git history it looks as though those files have never been committed. Has anyone else seen any migration scripts to retrospectiva floating around?

thanks
Mike

Comment: Retrospectiva looked promising, but shows little activity on their web page.